# WinSCP .NET library: Connect to SFTP server without specifying SSH host key fingerprint

Tags: ssh, sftp, public-key, winscp, winscp-net

In the current stable release of WinSCP, it seems that using `SshHostKeyFingerprint` is mandatory and there are no ways to connect to SFTP server without that in `SessionOptions`. I can see that the ability to bypass is added to the beta (5.2) but I was wondering whether or not it's possible to connect without this fingerprint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure you understand that you give-up *any security*, when you try to bypass SSH host key check. You effectively lose a protection against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Anyway, you can set the [`SessionOptions.SshHostKeyPolicy`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#sshhostkeypolicy) to `SshHostKeyPolicy.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAny`.

*It's NOT recommended though.* You should always set `SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint`.
Learn how to [determine SSH host key fingerprint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey). Or at least use the `SshHostKeyPolicy.AcceptNew`.

See also [Suppress the use of host key in SFTP or SCP using WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24188707/850848).

Comment: So what's the recommended way when you are connecting to a third party server the admin of which refuses to give you the ssh host key fingerprint stating security concerns?

Comment: Tell the admin, he's an i****t. Fingerprint of the host public key is public information by definition. There's no security concern at all. Anyway you can get the fingerprint yourself (as it's public). You just possibly do not have a way to get it strictly securely. You can see it for instance on [Server and Protocol Information Dialog](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo) in WinSCP GUI. For details see [Where do I get SSH hostkey fingerprint for use with scripting or .NET assembly?](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_hostkey)