# WinSCP: Too many parameters for command 'ls'

Tags: winscp

I'm getting error:

> Too many parameters for command 'ls'.

Command:

```
ls \X2269**\Ftp_Test\ > \X2269**\Ftp_Test\out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP script commands do not support output redirection.

You can only redirect the whole output of WinSCP.

You may also want to check this WinSCP article: [Custom directory listing format (CSV)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_custom_listing_format_csv).

Comment: Martin Prikryl: Is there any way to use .net assembly without fingerprint.

Comment: Do you mean this? [WinSCP .NET library: Connect to SFTP server without specifying SSH host key fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17938825/850848).

Comment: No, When using .net assembly from Powershell.

Comment: It does not matter what language do you use the assembly from. That question is not about any specific language.